# Iterate ASP.NET MVC views to find all views supporting a specific model type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, reflection

I would like to get a list of all views that support rendering a specific model type.

Pseudo code:

```
IEnumerable GetViewsByModelType(Type modelType)
{
   foreach (var view in SomeWayToGetAllViews())
   {
      if (typeof(view.ModelType).IsAssignableFrom(modelType))
      {
         yield return view; // This view supports the specified model type
      }
   }
}
```

In other words, given that I have a MyClass model, I'd like to find all views that would support rendering it. I.e. all views where the @model type is MyClass, or a type in its inheritance chain.

Comment: By the way - what's the purpose?

Comment: Part of a prototype for creating a "Wordpress-esque" templating system for an MVC-based CMS where new templates can simply be dropped inside the project and resolved at runtime.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on my findings the compiled views are not included in the assembly, so it's not going to be a walk in the park reflection.

In my opinion your best bet is going to be to list the `.cshtml` razor views and then use the `BuildManager` class to compile the type, which will allow you to get the Model property type.

Here is an example of looking for all Razor views that have a @Model type of LoginViewModel:

```
var dir = Directory.GetFiles(string.Format("{0}/Views", HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath), 
    "*.cshtml", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (var file in dir)
{
    var relativePath = file.Replace(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, String.Empty);

    Type type = BuildManager.GetCompiledType(relativePath);

    var modelProperty = type.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Model");

    if (modelProperty != null && modelProperty.PropertyType == typeof(LoginViewModel))
    {
        // You got the correct type
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I ended up doing something like that. Thanks for helping!

Comment: var relativePath = file.Replace(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, "~"); I had to change this line to get it working

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Faris Zacina´s answer I came up with this code:

```
string[] GetViews<TModel>(string virtualPath)
{
    var physicalPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(virtualPath);
    
    return Directory
        .GetFiles(physicalPath, "*.cshtml", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
        .Select(viewPath => virtualPath + "/" + Path.GetFileName(viewPath))
        .Where(virtualViewPath => BuildManager.GetCompiledType(virtualViewPath).GetProperty("Model", typeof(TModel)) != null)
        .ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finding the views via IO operations works only during development since they don't exist as physical files after publish (you get DLLs after all). If you need to get the views at runtime you need to resolve **ViewsFeature** from the **ApplicationPartManager** service:

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation;
    
    public class MyService
    {
        private readonly ApplicationPartManager _applicationPartManager;

        public MyService(ApplicationPartManager applicationPartManager)
        {
            _applicationPartManager = applicationPartManager;
        }

        public IList<CompiledViewDescriptor> GetAllViews()
        {
            var viewsFeature = new ViewsFeature();
            _applicationPartManager.PopulateFeature(viewsFeature);

            return viewsFeature.ViewDescriptors;
        }
    }
```